# How to specify indents to Text Views?

Tags: android

What value should I change?
I"ve an `.xml` file that contains all the text representations for the display table rows.
I've an adapter, which is fine to display all in the `main_activity.xml`.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Paddings: `paddingTop`,`paddingLeft`, `paddingRight`, `paddingBottom`

  or
- Margins: `layout_marginTop`,`layout_marginLeft`, `layout_marginRight`, `layout_marginBottom`

  depending on your exact needs.

Comment: How can I align components?

Comment: Align how exactly? Typically, any sort of alignments will be done by placing the text views in a RelativeLayout though it can also be done via LinearLayout

Comment: "How can I align components?" is a really general question. That's like a whole another issue with thousands possible solutions. Why don't you post another question, add your code, and the describe the desired effect. The community will for sure try to help you with your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute `layout_marginLeft`, `layout_marginRight`, `layout_marginTop` and `layout_marginBottom` to specify indents.

**Here is an example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="This is a sample text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a recyclerView or ListView and you are using a List Item layout for each instance.

In your list item layout:

Set a textView for each item in each row.

Then for each textview use either a fixed layout_width or use Layout_width="0" in conjunction with Layout_weight to space your textviews.
(fixed Layou_width is easier, but using Layout_Weight will auto adjust for screen orientation)

then your spacing will be consistent from row to row because it is based on the layout definitions and not the inserted text.